# JavaScript WYSIWYG text editors

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, text-editor, rich-text-editor

I'm writing a heavily-customised WordPress CMS for a fishkeeping website. Currently I'm working on the species profiles which consist of a load of small fields (Genus, Species, Diet, Compatibility, etc).

I'd like to use the built-in TinyMCE rich text editor, but WordPress appears to only allow the use of this editor on the large "Post" box, which I'm not using at all.

As such, I'm looking into alternative WYSIWYG editors, but I have some precise requirements:

- Needs to be lightweight, as there will be around 15 instances of the editor on the page
- On the same page, I need to be able to set different sizes for the different instances of the editor. Some will be say 200px wide, others 400px wide.
- Needs to have a "special characters" toolbar item, and preferably a spell-checking module, along with your standard b, em, ol and ul.
- Would be ideal if I could have a small number of rows with a minimised toolbar, i.e. just bold and italic with a single row of text.

In an ideal world, I'd like to be able to set up three different instances of the editor on a single page:

- A single row textarea with bold and italic toolbar items, at about 200px width
- A four row textarea with b, em, ol, ul, specialchars, spellchecking with 200px width
- A twelve row textarea with b, em, ol, ul, specialchars, spellchecking at about 400px width

I've tried using a separately-linked version of TinyMCE and it works generally, but the interface appears to only allow one width per page.

I've tried using ckeditor but I get an odd bug where all of the toolbar items appear in a vertical column rather than rows and I can't find any kind of support for it on their forums.

Does anyone have any suggestions for such a flexible rich text editor?

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT**

I have now tried jHtmlArea (no Special Characters or Spell-checking modules and an issue in FireFox where CTRL+I and CTRL+B shortcuts don't work); nicEdit (not quite flexible enough, though it's lovely in its simplicity) and YUI (don't like the number of dependencies required).

As such, I would like to add two further requirements:

- Keyboard shortcuts must work in recent versions of FireFox, Internet Explorer and Chrome
- At most, the editor must only state jQuery as a dependency

Comment: You could use javascript to resize them after the page has loaded and the TinyMCE areas have been initialised.

Comment: Hi Andrew. Could you give me an example of how I'd go about doing this?

Comment: Do you use the jQuery version of TinyMCE?  If so I can give you some code, otherwise I can make some guesses.

Comment: Not using either at the moment but it would be the jQuery TinyMCE I'd prefer to use, thanks.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond yesterday, I had to fly, but I added some of my code below

Comment: That kind of problem in CKEditor is usually due to a conflict with the CSS of your site, but I bet that you didn't publish any url for other people to take a look at what can be the problem.

Comment: Alfonso, no you're correct I didn't - the site isn't secured and as such inaccessible to the general public. It likely was a CSS issue, and I explored that avenue in some depth, but resigned myself to a different plugin when I couldn't find any support on the issue, especially considering that I wouldn't be able to publicise the page for people to investigate the issue. There was one further issue with ckedit but I can't for the life of me remember what it was.

Comment: Even if you can't publish a direct link to your site, you can always save the page, strip out any private information and use that simpler page as a testcase so other people can help you find out what's the problem. Anyway, using 15 instances of CKEditor at the same time is not the best idea and maybe that was your other issue.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this

1. [YUI editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/)
2. [nicedit](http://nicedit.com/)
3. https://code.google.com/p/wmd/
   [image]
4. http://livepipe.net/projects/control_textarea/
   [image]
5. https://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/
   [image]

hope you can use it

Comment: Hi Albert; I've updated my post with thoughts on these editors. Thanks.

Comment: I did actually try jwysiwyg but couldn't find any documentation so I struggled for a bit, got frustrated then decided to look at other implementations.

Comment: _jwysiwyg_ have some htmls in the **examples** folder for you to tweak

Comment: Thanks again for updating your post Albert. `Control Textarea` appears not to have keyboard shortcuts and the WMD live demo site doesn't appear to resolve for me. The examples provided by `jwysiwyg` weren't enough to help me solve the problems I was having with the editor.

Answer (score 1):

So to have two instances of a different size, you can just initialize them separately and give a different width:

```
$('#textarea1').tinymce({
    // Location of TinyMCE script
    script_url: '/Resources/Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
    // General options
    theme: "advanced",
    plugins: "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",
    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "cut,copy,paste,|,undo,redo,|,bold,italic,underline,forecolor,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
    theme_advanced_buttons4: "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "none",
    theme_advanced_resizing: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 700,
    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css: "css/content.css"
});
$('#textarea2').tinymce({
    // Location of TinyMCE script
    script_url: '/Resources/Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
    // General options
    theme: "advanced",
    plugins: "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",
    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "cut,copy,paste,|,undo,redo,|,bold,italic,underline,forecolor,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
    theme_advanced_buttons4: "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "none",
    theme_advanced_resizing: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css: "css/content.css"
});
```

This is what I am using, and you can see at the bottom of the "Theme options" section I have a width declaration.

Comment: I'm working on this now Andrew; hopefully it'll be exactly what I'm looking for. I'll pop back later and award the "correct answer" to you once I can get past this little problem I'm having with plugins not being loaded..!

Comment: Andrew, I've posted the problem I'm having over on the WordPress stack as I think I may be having compatibility problems. Just in case it's actually something to do with my tinyMCE installation, could you quickly cast your eyes over it for me? URL is here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37359/wordpress-tinymce-failed-to-load

Comment: dunc, sorry I am not on the ball replying, its the holiday season :p  Anyways, it looks like the plug ins added by tiny_mce can't be found.  In the above scripts there is a `script_url` attribute, make sure that is set correctly, and make sure all the plugins associated with tiny_mce are set up correctly in the same directory as tiny_mce.js.

Comment: No worries Andrew, I'm just grateful for your input :) The script_url is definitely set correctly (initially it wasn't and the script wouldn't load at all). The tiny_mce directory is laid out with `langs`, `plugins`, `themes` and `utils` directories as I think is correct. Oddly the Firebug debugging seems to indicate the problems are lying from an external call of jquery.js which would imply it's a WordPress compatibility problem I suspect.